Wastegate is malfunctioning. Can I replace wastegate without replacing turbo charger?
Diagnostic test on my 2015 X5 BMW showed the wastegate is malfunctioning. Can I replace wastegate without replacing turbo charger?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Like so many answers, the theme here is: it depends. Part of it stems from what @GdG stated in whether it's integrated with the turbo or not. Like he states, if it's integrated, you cannot replace it separately.
What is causing the current wastegate to fail? Is it the actuator or the wastegate itself? If it's the actuator, you can most likely fix it without changing out the turbo. If it's not closing properly because there is interference or because there's no longer a seal (damaged or worn out where valve meets mating surface), then you may be able to get away with refurbishing it while the turbo is off the car, but most likely a new turbo is in order.
There are probably other examples I could give as well, but your question isn't really specific as to what exactly is going on.

Although some turbo systems have separate wastegates, most are integrated with the turbo and cannot be replaced separately, including the turbo on your X5. Once removed, a malfunctioning wastegate can be repaired or replaced if the turbo is disassembled and refurbished, which is certainly an option for you if you need to save some money.
